# Fitnesse regular expression with pipe

Tags: regex, fitnesse

I am using fitnesse, and i need to match 2 possible outputs.

My script table looks like this:

```
|script|MyClass|
|check|doSomething|value|=~/Result1|Result2/|
```

My problem is that the pipe | in the regex is read as a column separator instead. Is there a way to escape the pipe character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick googling brought this escape sequence up:

```
!-|-!
```

See [here](http://old.nabble.com/escape-%7C-%28vertical-bar%29-in-fitnesse-wiki-td22298159.html), [here](http://old.nabble.com/Use-of-Pipe-%28%7C%29-in-fitnesse-td16631663.html) and [here](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide).

For increased readability you should probably use it like this:

```
|check|doSomething|value|!-=~/Result1|Result2/-!|
```

Comment: @Dorus Try "fitnesse escape pipe" :P

Comment: That works better then "Fitnesse escape regex" and all variations i tried.